# add or subtract sets of ranges like "1,2,4,10-25,40+" + "3,11,26"

Tags: c#, collections, range

I am writing a C# program where the user can enter a range of values in sets, like "1,2,4,10-25,40+" where the items can be individual number, a range like 10-25, and a range to infinity like 25+. The ranges must be at least 2 apart, you cannot say 10-11, that should be 10,11.
I need functions to add and subtract them.

For example, "1,2,4,10-25,40+" + "3,11,26" would return "1-4,10-26,40+"

I am using strings for example purposes here, but assume the data could be already parsed into objects for the three categories: single number, range, infinite range. I'm not asking how to parse strings.

I am writing my own set of functions, and seeing that there is a lot of complexity due to the fact that the ranges must be 2 apart. I know there are functions to test if a number is in one range, and that is easy to build into a routine to test if a number is in a set of ranges.

But how can I add or subtract sets, and simplify them so you do not get 11,12,13 but 11-13 instead? That is not trivial. I am open to any solution and can import libraries if it's required.

Comment: What's the endgame of these ranges?  Seems pretty arbitrary.  Please include expected output and any code you have.

Comment: So you want something that if a user enters `11,12,13`, it will change that to be `11-13`?

Comment: @JRLambert: I believe that it should also do `"1,2,4" + "3" = "1-4"`. There are basically two questions here, one about simplifying and one about adding and subtracting.

Comment: Let's see your set of functions, please.

Comment: The end goal is to allow users to maintain a list of row numbers they are not allowed to use. They can add or remove numbers from that list using these functions. They do need to simplify the results. I'll post what I have in a bit since I get so much from SO.

Comment: I posted my code below, it has functions for turning strings in "sequences" = List<List<int>> and cleaning, combining, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little function I wrote to help you out...[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zecPOR)

### Snippet

```
private static List<string> Simplify(List<string> inputs)
{
    var simpleList = new List<int>();
    var retval = new List<string>();
    bool infinity = false;

    foreach (string input in inputs)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            continue;

        if (input.Split('-').Length > 1)
        {
            int min = int.Parse(input.Split('-')[0].Trim());
            int max = int.Parse(input.Split('-')[1].Trim());

            // inclusive
            simpleList.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1));

            continue;
        }

        if (input.Trim().EndsWith("+"))
        {
            infinity = true;
            simpleList.Add(int.Parse(input.Trim().Trim('+')));
        } else simpleList.Add(int.Parse(input.Trim()));
    }

    simpleList.Sort();

    for (int i = 0; i < simpleList.Count; i++)
    {
        int currentVal = simpleList[i];
        int q = i;
        while (q < simpleList.Count)
        {
            if (q != simpleList.Count - 1 && simpleList[q] + 1 == simpleList[q + 1])
            {
                q++;
                continue;
            }
            if (currentVal == simpleList[q])
            {
                retval.Add(currentVal.ToString());
                i = q;
                break;
            }
            if (currentVal + 1 == simpleList[q])
            {
                retval.Add(currentVal.ToString());
                retval.Add(simpleList[q].ToString());
                i = q;
                break;
            }
            retval.Add(currentVal + "-" + simpleList[q]);
            i = q;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (infinity)
        retval[retval.Count - 1] = retval[retval.Count - 1] + "+";

    return retval;
}
```

### Test Case:

```
var inputs = new List<string> {"11", "12", "13", "14-18", "2-3", "25", "82+", "9"};

var simplifiedList = Simplify(inputs);

foreach (string input in simplifiedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```

### Output:

```
2
3
9
11-18
25
82+
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is my set of functions.
I define my sequence terms as a list of ints (all positive BTW), where a single num is (num), range is (start end) and infinite range is (num -1).
In strings, I allow - or | for range separator.
I might have left out a couple extension methods, I think I got them though.
I know the spaces look ugly online, you need to copy and paste into a .cs file to see nicely. I jsut copied and pasted from VS.

to test, try things like this: (they purposefully have odd values..)

List> result = AddSequences(StringToSequence("10,11,12-14,20-30,40+"), StringToSequence("15,16,21-41,50+"));

List> result = SubtractSequences(StringToSequence("10,11,20-30,40+"), StringToSequence("21-41,50+"));

List> result = StringToSequence("1-5,8,10,11-29,30+, 19-25,30-40, 50+, 60+");

```
    //-------------------sequence tools-----------------------------
    public static string SequenceToString(List<List<int>> seq) {
    string ret = "";
    foreach (List<int> pair in seq) {
        if (pair.Count == 1)
        ret = ret + pair[0].ToString() + ",";
        else {
        if (pair[1] != -1)
            ret = ret + pair[0].ToString() + "|" + pair[1].ToString() + ",";
        else
            ret = ret + pair[0].ToString() + "+,";
        }
    }
    return ret;
    }

public static List<List<int>> StringToSequence(string seq) {
    List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();
    //make sure we have a list of integers
    //turn into a List<List<int>>
    //use -1 as second item to indicate the +
    List<List<int>> pairs = new List<List<int>>();
    //int usesPlus = -1;
    //split by commas
    string[] items = seq.RemoveCharsExcept("|.,-+").Split(',');
    foreach (string str in items) {
    //see if we have a dash
    if (str.Contains("-") || str.Contains("|")) {
        string[] tmp1;
        if (str.Contains("-"))
        tmp1 = str.Split('-');
        else 
        tmp1 = str.Split('|');
        //the RemoveChars() is to get rid of a + if there
        if (tmp1.Count() == 2 && tmp1[0].RemoveChars().IsInteger() && tmp1[1].RemoveChars().IsInteger()) {
        int int1 = tmp1[0].RemoveChars().ToInteger();
        int int2 = tmp1[1].RemoveChars().ToInteger();
        if (int2 > int1)
            if (int2 - int1 == 1) {
            pairs.Add(new List<int>() { int1 });
            pairs.Add(new List<int>() { int2 });
            }
            else
            pairs.Add(new List<int>() { int1, int2 });
        }
    }
    else if (str.RemoveChars().IsInteger()) {
        int tmp = str.RemoveChars().ToInteger();
        if (str.Right(1) == "+")
        pairs.Add(new List<int>() { str.RemoveChars().ToInteger(), -1 });
        else
        pairs.Add(new List<int>() { str.RemoveChars().ToInteger() });
    }
    }
    //now sort list by first item
    ret = pairs.OrderBy(o => o[0]).ToList();
    DelSequenceDupes(ret);
    CombineSequenceNums(ret);
    CombineSequenceMergeNumsToSeqs(ret);
    CombineSequenceSeqs(ret);
    TrimSequenceByPlusNums(ret);
    return ret;
}

//all these assume items are in order by first element
public static List<List<int>> AddSequences(List<List<int>> origSeq, List<List<int>> addSeq) {
    List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();
    //add in items and clean up
    origSeq.AddRange(addSeq);
    //sort list by first item
    ret = origSeq.OrderBy(o => o[0]).ToList();
    DelSequenceDupes(ret);
    CombineSequenceNums(ret);
    CombineSequenceMergeNumsToSeqs(ret);
    CombineSequenceSeqs(ret);
    TrimSequenceByPlusNums(ret);
    return ret;
}

public static List<List<int>> DelSequenceDupes(List<List<int>> seq) {
    List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();
    List<int> prev = new List<int>();
    foreach (List<int> pair in seq) {
    if (prev.Count == 0) {
        ret.Add(pair);
        prev = pair;
    }
    else if (prev.Count != pair.Count || prev[0] != pair[0] || prev[1] != pair[1]) {
        ret.Add(pair);
        prev = pair;
    }
    }
    return ret;
}

public static List<List<int>> CombineSequenceNums(List<List<int>> seq) {
    List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();
    int conscount = 0;
    int previtem = -1;
    foreach (List<int> pair in seq) {
    if (pair.Count == 1) {
        if (conscount == 0) {
        previtem = pair[0];
        conscount++;
        }
        else {
        if (pair[0] == previtem + 1) {
            previtem = pair[0];
            conscount++;
        }
        //else deal with any sequences or not, and start over
        else {
            if (conscount < 3) {
            for (int i = conscount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { previtem - i });
            }
            }
            //else its a sequence
            else {
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { previtem - (conscount - 1), previtem });
            }
            //start over on this number
            previtem = pair[0];
            conscount = 1;
        }
        }
    }
    else {
        //if on a sequence, see if conscount is more than 2
        if (conscount < 3) {
        for (int i = conscount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { previtem - i });
        }
        }
        //else its a sequence
        else {
        ret.Add(new List<int>() { previtem - (conscount - 1), previtem });
        }
        //start over on bogus previtem
        previtem = -1;
        conscount = 0;
        //now add the sequence as is
        ret.Add(pair);
    }
    }
    //add any hanging numbers
    //if on a sequence, see if conscount is more than 2
    if (conscount < 3) {
    for (int i = conscount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ret.Add(new List<int>() { previtem - i });
    }
    }
    //else its a sequence
    else {
    ret.Add(new List<int>() { previtem - (conscount - 1), previtem });
    }
    return ret;
}

public static List<List<int>> CombineSequenceSeqs(List<List<int>> seq) {
    List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();
    List<int> prevseq = new List<int>();
    foreach (List<int> pair in seq) {
    if (pair.Count == 1) {
        //add previous sequence if any
        if (prevseq.Count > 0) {
        ret.Add(prevseq);
        prevseq = new List<int>();
        }
        ret.Add(pair);
    }
    //else if a sequence
    else {
        if (pair[1] == -1) {
        //add previous sequence if any
        if (prevseq.Count > 0) {
            ret.Add(prevseq);
            prevseq = new List<int>();
        }
        ret.Add(pair);
        }
        else {
        if (prevseq.Count == 0) {
            prevseq = pair;
        }
        //if adjacent or any overlap, combine
        else {
            if (prevseq[1] + 1 >= pair[0]) {
            prevseq = new List<int>() { prevseq[0], Math.Max(pair[1], prevseq[1]) };
            }
            else {
            ret.Add(prevseq);
            prevseq = pair;
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
    //add at end
    if (prevseq.Count > 0)
    ret.Add(prevseq);
    return ret;
}

public static List<List<int>> CombineSequenceMergeNumsToSeqs(List<List<int>> seq) {
    List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();
    int index = 0;
    while (index < seq.Count) {
    List<int> pair = seq[index];
    //if a number, add to ret
    if (pair.Count == 1 || (pair.Count == 2 && pair[1] == -1)) {
        ret.Add(pair);
        index++;
    }
    else {
        //if on a seq, look behind and ahead for numbers to gobble
        int lookback = 1;
        List<int> newpair = pair;
        bool go = true;
        while (go &&
           index > 0 &&
           index - lookback > -1) {
        if (seq[index - lookback].Count == 1 &&
            seq[index - lookback][0] == newpair[0] - 1) {
            //remove last item from ret
            ret.RemoveAt(ret.Count - 1);
            //modify newpair
            newpair[0] = newpair[0] - 1;
            lookback++;
        }
        else
            go = false;
        }
        //now look ahead, careful to get rid of item in the range already
        int lookahd = 1;
        go = true;
        while (go &&
           index < seq.Count + 1 &&
           index + lookahd < seq.Count) {
        if (seq[index + lookahd].Count == 1) {
            //if in range already
            if (seq[index + lookahd][0] <= newpair[1])
            lookahd++;
            else if (seq[index + lookahd][0] == newpair[1] + 1) {
            //modify newpair
            newpair[1] = newpair[1] + 1;
            lookahd++;
            }
            else
            go = false;
        }
        else
            go = false;
        }
        //add newpair to ret
        ret.Add(newpair);
        //jump past items done
        index = index + lookahd;
    }
    }
    return ret;
}

public static List<List<int>> TrimSequenceByPlusNums(List<List<int>> seq) {
    List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();
    //get sequence info
    int lowPlsNum;
    int highest = FindHighestInSeq(seq, out lowPlsNum);
    if (lowPlsNum != -1) {
    foreach (List<int> pair in seq) {
        if (pair.Count == 1) {
        if (pair[0] < lowPlsNum)
            ret.Add(pair);
        }
        else {
        if (pair[1] == -1) {
            if (pair[0] == lowPlsNum)
            ret.Add(pair);
        }
        else {
            if (pair[1] < lowPlsNum) {
            ret.Add(pair);
            }
            else if (pair[0] < lowPlsNum && pair[1] >= lowPlsNum)
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { pair[0], lowPlsNum - 1 });
        }
        }
    }
    }
    else
    ret = seq;
    return ret;
}

//assumes subtSeq has been cleaned so items are in order
public static List<List<int>> SubtractSequences(List<List<int>> origSeq, List<List<int>> subtSeq) {
    List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();
    if (subtSeq.Count > 0) {
    //go through origSeq and modify any items
    foreach (List<int> pair in origSeq) {
        //case 1 - just one number
        if (pair.Count == 1) {
        if (!IsPtInSequence(subtSeq, pair[0]))
            //add if not in subt sequence
            ret.Add(pair);
        }
        //case 2 - a sequence in orig
        else if (pair.Count == 2 && pair[1] != -1) {
        //must chop up based on items in subt
        List<List<int>> res = SubtractFromNonPlusSequence(pair, subtSeq);
        if (res.Count > 0)
            ret.AddRange(res);
        }
        //a number+
        else if (pair.Count == 2 && pair[1] == -1) {
        List<List<int>> res = SubtractFromPlusSequence(pair, subtSeq);
        if (res.Count > 0)
            ret.AddRange(res);
        }
    }
    }
    return ret;
}
//subtract a num+ by sequence
//origSeq  must have a -1 as second item
public static List<List<int>> SubtractFromPlusSequence(List<int> origSeq, List<List<int>> subtSeq) {
    List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();
    //handle by converting the num+ to a sequence plus a num+ if needed
    //find largest number in subtSeq
    int lowPlsNum;
    int largest = FindHighestInSeq(subtSeq, out lowPlsNum);
    List<int> tmpseq;
    //now make temp sequence
    if (lowPlsNum == -1) {
    //return original as its all before
    if (largest < origSeq[0]) {
        ret = new List<List<int>>() { origSeq };
    }
    else {
        //if overlap of 1
        if (largest - origSeq[0] == 1) {
        if (!IsPtInSequence(subtSeq, origSeq[0]))
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { origSeq[0] });
        }
        else if (largest - origSeq[0] == 2) {
        if (!IsPtInSequence(subtSeq, origSeq[0]))
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { origSeq[0] });
        if (!IsPtInSequence(subtSeq, origSeq[0] + 1))
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { origSeq[0] + 1 });
        }
        else {
        tmpseq = new List<int>() { origSeq[0], largest - 1 };
        ret.AddRange(SubtractFromNonPlusSequence(tmpseq, subtSeq));
        }
        //add a plus after all, since subtSeq did not have a +num in it
        ret.Add(new List<int>() { largest + 1, -1 });
    }
    }
    else {
    //its got a plus in it, just do before the subtract +
    if (lowPlsNum - origSeq[0] == 1) {
        ret.Add(new List<int>() { origSeq[0] });
    }
    else if (lowPlsNum - origSeq[0] == 2) {
        ret.Add(new List<int>() { origSeq[0] });
        ret.Add(new List<int>() { origSeq[0] + 1 });
    }
    else {
        tmpseq = new List<int>() { origSeq[0], lowPlsNum - 1 };
        ret.AddRange(SubtractFromNonPlusSequence(tmpseq, subtSeq));
    }
    //else return blank as it got wiped out
    }
    return ret;
}

//subtract a sequence (2 items) using another
public static List<List<int>> SubtractFromNonPlusSequence(List<int> origSeq, List<List<int>> subtSeq) {
    List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();
    //as we go along, curseq will be the term at hand to possibly chop
    List<int> curseq = origSeq;
    bool done = false;
    foreach (List<int> chopr in subtSeq) {
    if (!done) {
        //if chopping with one number
        if (chopr.Count == 1) {
        #region Chop with one
        //test if chop at all
        if (chopr[0] < curseq[0] || chopr[0] > curseq[1]) {
            ret.Add(curseq);
            done = true;
        }
        else {
            //handle left side of chop
            if (chopr[0] - curseq[0] == 1) {
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0] });
            }
            else if (chopr[0] - curseq[0] == 2) {
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0] });
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0] + 1 });
            }
            else if (chopr[0] - curseq[0] > 2) {
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0], chopr[0] - 1 });
            }
            //handle right side of chop
            if (curseq[1] - chopr[0] == 1) {
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[1] });
            done = true;
            }
            else if (curseq[1] - chopr[0] == 2) {
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[1] - 1 });
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[1] });
            done = true;
            }
            else if (curseq[1] - chopr[0] > 2) {
            curseq = new List<int>() { chopr[0] + 1, curseq[1] };
            }
        }
        }
        #endregion
        //now look at a chopper sequence
        else {
        //if a number +
        if (chopr[1] == -1) {
            #region Chop with one+
            //only 3 cases matter
            //if at or before start
            if (chopr[0] <= curseq[0]) {
            //stop
            done = true;
            }
            else if (chopr[0] > curseq[1]) {
            //do nothing
            }
            //if past start by 1
            else if (chopr[0] == curseq[0] + 1) {
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0] });
            done = true;
            }
            //if past start by 2
            else if (chopr[0] == curseq[0] + 2) {
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0] });
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0] + 1 });
            //stop here because discard the rest
            done = true;
            }
            //if past start by more than 2
            else {
            ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0], chopr[0] - 1 });
            done = true;
            }
        }
            #endregion
        //if a sequence
        else {
            #region Chop with seq
            //complete overlap
            if (curseq[0] >= chopr[0] && curseq[1] <= chopr[1]) {
            done = true;
            }
            //if we overlap chop start
            else if (chopr[1] == curseq[0]) {
            curseq = new List<int>() { curseq[0] + 1, curseq[1] };
            }
            //if we overlap chop end
            else if (chopr[0] == curseq[1]) {
            curseq = new List<int>() { curseq[0], curseq[1] - 1 };
            }
            //if we enclose chopper
            else if (chopr[0] > curseq[0] && chopr[1] < curseq[1]) {
            //handle left side
            if (chopr[0] - curseq[0] == 1) {
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0] });
            }
            else if (chopr[0] - curseq[0] == 2) {
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0] });
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0] + 1 });
            }
            else {
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0], chopr[0] - 1 });
            }
            //handle right side
            if (curseq[1] - chopr[1] == 1) {
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[1] });
                done = true;
            }
            else if (curseq[1] - chopr[1] == 2) {
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[1] - 1 });
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[1] });
                done = true;
            }
            else {
                curseq = new List<int>() { chopr[1] + 1, curseq[1] };
            }
            }
            //if we overlap past chop start
            else if (chopr[0] < curseq[0] && chopr[1] > curseq[0] && chopr[1] < curseq[1]) {
            //see if we leave nums or a sequence
            if (curseq[1] - chopr[1] == 1) {
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[1] });
                done = true;
            }
            else if (curseq[1] - chopr[1] == 2) {
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[1] - 1 });
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[1] });
                done = true;
            }
            else {
                curseq = new List<int>() { chopr[1] + 1, curseq[1] };
            }
            }
            //if we overlap before chop end
            else if (chopr[0] > curseq[0] && chopr[0] < curseq[1] && chopr[1] >= curseq[1]) {
            //see if we leave nums or a sequence
            if (chopr[0] - curseq[0] == 1) {
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0] });
                done = true;
            }
            else if (chopr[0] - curseq[0] == 2) {
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0] });
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0] + 1 });
                done = true;
            }
            else {
                ret.Add(new List<int>() { curseq[0], chopr[0] - 1 });
                done = true;
            }
            }
        }
            #endregion
        }
    }
    }
    if (!done)
    ret.Add(curseq);
    return ret;
}

//find highest number in sequence, as well as lowest +num if an
//lowPlsNum is -1 if not found
public static int FindHighestInSeq(List<List<int>> seq, out int lowPlsNum) {
    //find largest number in subtSeq
    int ret = 0;
    //track lowest num+ if found in subtSeq
    lowPlsNum = -1;
    foreach (List<int> pair in seq) {
    if (pair.Count == 1) {
        if (pair[0] > ret)
        ret = pair[0];
    }
    else if (pair.Count == 2 && pair[1] != -1) {
        if (pair[1] > ret)
        ret = pair[1];
    }
    else if (pair.Count == 2 && pair[1] == -1) {
        if (lowPlsNum == -1)
        lowPlsNum = pair[0];
        if (pair[0] < lowPlsNum)
        lowPlsNum = pair[0];
    }
    }
    return ret;
}

public static bool IsPtInSequence(List<List<int>> seq, int ptnum) {
    bool ret = false;
    foreach (List<int> lst in seq) {
    if (lst.Count == 1) {
        if (lst[0] == ptnum)
        ret = true;
    }
    else if (lst.Count == 2) {
        //check if plus item
        if (lst[1] == -1) {
        if (ptnum >= lst[0])
            ret = true;
        }
        else if (ptnum >= lst[0] && ptnum <= lst[1])
        ret = true;
    }
    }
    return ret;
}

public static string RemoveChars(this string s) {
    string str = "";
    foreach (char c in s) {
        if (char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.' || c == ',' || c == '-') {
            str = str + c.ToString();
        }
    }
    return str;
}

//keep is list of single chars
public static string RemoveCharsExcept(this string s, string keep) {
    string str = "";
    foreach (char c in s) {
    if (char.IsDigit(c) || keep.Contains(c)) {
        str = str + c.ToString();
    }
    }
    return str;
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns the last few characters of the string with a length
/// specified by the given parameter. If the string's length is less than the 
/// given length the complete string is returned. If length is zero or 
/// less an empty string is returned
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s">the string to process</param>
/// <param name="length">Number of characters to return</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string Right(this string s, int length) {
    length = Math.Max(length, 0);
    if (s.Length > length) {
        return s.Substring(s.Length - length, length);
    }
    else {
        return s;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns the first few characters of the string with a length
/// specified by the given parameter. If the string's length is less than the 
/// given length the complete string is returned. If length is zero or 
/// less an empty string is returned
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s">the string to process</param>
/// <param name="length">Number of characters to return</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string Left(this string s, int length) {
    length = Math.Max(length, 0);

    if (s.Length > length) {
        return s.Substring(0, length);
    }
    else {
        return s;
    }
}
public static string StripLeft(this string s, int length) {
    length = Math.Max(length, 0);

    if (s.Length > length) {
        return s.Substring(length);
    }
    else {
        return "";
    }
}
public static string StripRight(this string s, int length) {
    length = Math.Max(length, 0);

    if (s.Length > length) {
        return s.Substring(0, s.Length - length);
    }
    else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You hint that you have three different classes representing the three different types of ranges. You have a single aggregate range collection class, I hope? If not, create one. Here's a pseudocode algorithm for what to do when adding a new set to an existing one:

```
Add(RangeCollection collection2)
  for each int n in collection2.singles
    if n >= infinite_range_start: next n
    // there should only be one infinite range
    for each range r in ranges // ranges should be a sorted list
      if n = r.start - 1
        r.start = n
        next n
      if n = r.end + 1
        r.end = n
        next n
      if n < r.end: break
      if n >= r.start and n <= range.end: next n
    // at this point we know n is not within any ranges
    singles.Add(n) // should be a set
  CheckSinglesForRanges()
  MergeOverlappingRanges()
  CheckInfiniteRange()

CheckSinglesForRanges()
  singleList = singles.ToOrderedList()
  start = null
  end = null
  for each number n in singleList
    if start = null
      start = n
      next n
    if n = start + 1
      end = n
      next n
    if start != null and end != null and end > start + 1
      ranges.Add(new range(start, end))
      start = null
      end = null
  if start != null and end != null and end > start + 1
    ranges.Add(new range(start, end))

MergeOverLappingRanges()
  // ranges should be a list of range objects ordered by range.start
  prevR = null
  for each range r in ranges
    if prevR = null
      prevR = r
      next r
    if prevR.end >= r.start
      prevR.end = r.end
      ranges.Remove(r)
      next r
    prevR = r

CheckInfiniteRange()
  if singles.largest = inifinite_range_start - 1
    inifinite_range_start--
    CheckInfiniteRange()
  if ranges.last.end >= inifinite_range_start - 1
    inifinite_range_start = ranges.last.start
    ranges.remove(ranges.last)
    singles.RemoveAll(where n >= infinite_range_start)
    CheckInfiniteRange()

Subtract(RangeCollection collection2)
  for each number n in collection2.singles
    if singles.Contains(n)
      singles.remove(n)
      next n
    for each range r in ranges
      if n = r.start
        r.start++
        next n
      if n = r.end
        r.end--
        next n
      if n > r.start and n < r.end: 
        if n = r.start + 1
          singles.add(r.start)
          ranges.add(new range(n + 1, r.end))
        if n = r.end - 1
          singles.add(r.end)
          ranges.add(new range(n.start, n - 1))
        else
          ranges.add(new range(r.start, n - 1))
          ranges.add(new range(n + 1, r.end))
        ranges.Remove(r)
        next n
    if n = infinite_range_start
      infinite_range_start++
      next n
    if n = infinite_range_start + 1
      singles.add(infinite_range_start)
      infinite_range_start = n + 1
      next n
    if n > infinite_range_start
      ranges.add(new range(infinite_range_start, n - 1))
      infinite_range_start = n + 1
      next n
```

Notes:

- I have only shown how to handle working with single numbers. I leave it as an exercise for you to extend this to handle ranges. It shouldn't be hard to figure out.
- I haven't bothered to include basic defensiveness, such as checking for nulls or empty sets. You'll want that.
- I've made what I think are reasonable assumptions about what properties your three range classes expose.
- There are a couple places where a naive implementation will get a runtime error for removing an element from a list while traversing it. Your implementation will need to account for this; it should be easy to do so.
- This is robust against negative numbers with the exception that only increasing infinite ranges are allowed (moving towards positive infinity). For example, "10-" (meaning going from 10 down to negative infinity) is not a valid range. It's relatively simple to mirror the infinite range code if you need that functionality.